# How do stars other than the sun increase with luminosity along the main sequence?

Tags: astrophysics

Caldeira and Kasting (1992) used the approximation
$$
\frac{L}{L_0} = \frac{1}{1 + 0.38 (1 - t/t_0)}
$$
for the Sun's luminosity increase as it aged, where t is the age and t0 the present age (~ 4.55 billion years).  Does anyone know where I can find a similar expression for stars of spectral types other than G2V, or masses other than 1 Solar mass?

Comment: Note that there is an Astronomy SE as well.

Comment: In future, please use MathJaX (a browser-based implementation of LaTeX) to write equations on this forum.  [Here's a tutorial on how to do so.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  I have taken the liberty of correcting the equation in this particular question.

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32771/is-there-a-way-to-factor-age-into-the-mass-luminosity-relationship-for-stars